# Printing json data in string format

Tags: python, json

I have many json fields in my model. I want to print them in the string format.

The code I am using is :

```
data=[]
detail=details.objects.filter(Id=item['Id'])
for i in compliance:
     data.append(str("Name")+str(":")+str(i.Name)+str(" , ")+str("Details")+str(":")+str(i.Details)

print data
```

The output I am getting is :

```
Name:ABC, Details:{u'Status': u'True', u'Remarks': u'No Remark'}
```

The expected output is:

```
Name:ABC, Details:Status:True,Remarks:No Remark
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your expected output isn't valid JSON

Comment: Don't concatenate strings. Append them to a list and use `str.join` method

Answer (score 0):

Check if your data is of type dict

1. If not print as you are doing now
2. If yes then send dictionary to another function which does as below

   `def print_dict(d):
     return ",".join([key+":"+str(d[key]) for key in d])`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way, assuming `compliance` is a dict / json.

- Save the key dicts in a list
- Iterate over that list and build a concatenated list

Code would look like this:

```
keyorder = ['Name', 'Status', 'Remarks']   
res = []
for key in keyorder:  
    res.append(key + ':' + compliance[key])

', '.join(res)

'Name:ABC, Status:True, Remarks:No remarks'
```

Answer (score 0):

As @chkri suggested check first if your data is dict if yes then you can try this one line solution:

```
dict={'Name':'ABC', 'Details':{u'Status': u'True', u'Remarks': u'No Remark'}}


print({k:v for k,v in dict.items()})
```

output:

```
{'Name': 'ABC', 'Details': {'Remarks': 'No Remark', 'Status': 'True'}}
```